# Daemon Output not being written to a TXT

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have a script that calls functions from a daemon server. The daemon server generates an output each time it finishes its job. The daemon mainly downloads files from an outside server. The daemon source code is closed (coded by an external company).

Daemon Output Example after it finishs downloading the file:

```
Saved to /home/ubuntu/Daemon/downloads/download_1024000003.pdf
```

The script i'm using gets ids of the downloads from a TXT file, Username of the PC for the From User Field , and put them in an array then call them from the Daemon get the file then write a log in a txt file.

The Log Sample should be:

```
Documnent ID= 3
From User = DomainCon
Saved to /home/ubuntu/Daemon/downloads/download_1024000003.pdf
```

the problem I'm facing is that **Saved to /home/ubuntu/Daemon/downloads/download_1024000003.pdf** which the daemon server generates everytime a download finishes is sometimes missing in the TXT.

Problem Example:

```
Documnent ID= 2
From User = DomainCon
Documnent ID= 3
In Chat = DomainCon
ANSWER 78
Saved to /home/ubuntu/Daemon/downloads/download_1024000003.pdf
```

The output in the log file *should* be:

```
Documnent ID= 2
From User = DomainCon
ANSWER 96
Saved to /home/ubuntu/Daemon/downloads/download_1024000002.pdf
Documnent ID= 3
In Chat = DomainCon
ANSWER 78
Saved to /home/ubuntu/Daemon/downloads/download_1024000003.pdf
```

this is the Script I'm using including comments:

```
for i in range(len(ids)):\\ ids is the array that contains the documents that should be downloaded.
       cmdping = "sleep 5; echo load_document "+ids[i][0]+"| nc -w 4 127.0.0.1 1234 | tee >> "+logtxt \\ Perpare the Echo  command to the daemon to start the download tee to save the output of the daemon into the log text
       print("\033[1;31m~~~Documnent~~~NB~~~"+str(i+1)+"\033[1;m")
       print ("Documnent ID= "+ids[i][0])\\ Just Print on screen for Debbuging Purpose
       print ("From User= "+ids[i][1])\\Just Print on screen for Debbuging Purpose
       logfile = open(logtxt, "a") \\ Open the TXT where the log is gonna be saved.
       logfile.write("Documnent ID= "+ids[i][0]+"\n")\\Write the Document ID in the File.
       logfile.write("From User = "+ids[i][1]+"\n")\\\\Write the From User in the File.
       logfile.close()\\Close the logfile
       if (i==len(ids)-1):
          p=subprocess.Popen(cmdping, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)\\ Start the proccess that was prepared before.
          #time.sleep(1)
          check=""
          s=1
          skip=0
          while (s==1):
              check=checkfile(srcdir)
              if (check!="no"):
                 s=2
              if(check=="skip"):
                 skip=1
          if(skip!=1):
             if(checksize(srcdir+check) == "done"):
                print(check+"\n \033[1;32mFinished Downloading moving to the next download\033[1;m")
          p.terminate()
          user_dir=rootdir+"/document/"+ids[i][1];
          checkandcopy(download,user_dir)
```

Comment: Is this maybe a race condition? what if `checkfile()` and/or `checksize()`return the expected value before your daemon has written to the file and then it gets terminated by `p.terminate()` before ever writing to the log? "Sometimes it works and sometimes not" sounds like the typical race condition behavior...

Comment: the Daemon Create a file once it starts downloading, check file check if the file is created if not the checkfile return skip, because the file sometime is not available on the server then the Daemon return ID invalid, if the file is available check size get the check file location and keep checking if the file is growing bigger (by size) when it stop getting bigger it returns 2 which break the loop then termiate the proccess, do you suggest that i add a timer.sleep after the loop exit ?

Comment: shouldn't `cmdping` simply exit by itself once the other end of the `nc` connection is closed? If not, a `sleep` might work for you, but that is not really solving the race condition in itself. e.g. If your network has problems, the text might come a long time after the file has already finished and that might be longer than your `sleep`...

Comment: The other end NC never closes it's a daemon that keeps runing 24/7, yeah i think that the problem is with the network drop... do you have any idea how i can solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using a socket instead. Here's some inspiration:

```
import re
import socket
for i, (doc_id, user) in enumerate(ids):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("\033[1;31m~~~Documnent~~~NB~~~"+str(i+1)+"\033[1;m")
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
    s.sendall('load_document {}\n'.format(doc_id))
    buf = []
    while True:
        r = s.recv(4096).strip()
        print('Got {} for socket'.format(r))
        buf.append(r)
        if r.endswith('.pdf'):
            print('Done')
            break
    result = '\n'.join(buf)
    s.close()
    with open(logtxt, 'a') as f:
        f.write('Document ID= {}\n'.format(doc_id))
        f.write('From User = {}\n'.format(user))
        f.write('{}\n'.format(result))
    filename = re.search('Saved to (.+)$', result).group(1)
    checkandcopy(filename, userdir)
```

Comment: Could you please explain the code a little bit, i'm not familliar with socketing on python, thank you.

Comment: the files could be any format not PDF only, anyway i think i can fix this part.

Comment: @Z.Kiwan I took the `nc ... | tee` part of your code and did it in python instead. `s.connect` connects, `sendall` sends the `load document ` command  and `recv(4096).strip()` gets output from the connection.  Strip removes any excessive whitespace and newlines in general.When you've recived what you expect (for example a line that ends with .pdf or similar) then close the connection and write the output to the logtxt.

Comment: Sorry i'm miss understanding something here, s.recv(4096).strip() is only getting "saved to blablabla.pdf" but not the real PDF right ?, because when you send the command load_document the daemon automticaly downlaod data to 
Saved to /home/ubuntu/Daemon/downloads/ and i cannot change this path, how do you know that the download is done ?

Comment: It don't. It just reads what the server have written back when you write "load document" to it.

Comment: Do the server write "Saved to /home/ubuntu/Daemon/downloads/" before it's done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103110/discussion-between-svrist-and-z-kiwan).